# Batch Scripting: Running python script on all directories in a folder

Tags: python, batch-file

I have a python script called `script.py` which I would like to run on all of the directories inside of a specific directory. What is the easiest way to do this using batch scripting?

My assumption is some usage of the FOR command, but I can't quite make any leads to solve the problem using the command...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the /d operator on [for](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/for.mspx?mfr=true):

```
for /D %%d in (*) do script.py %%d
```

This assumes you only need to execute one command per directory (`script.py %%d`) if you need to execute more use braces `()`.  Also I'm guessing there's an execution engine needed first, but not sure what it is for you.

A multi-line example:

```
for /D %%d in (%1) do (
   echo processing %%d
   script.py %%d
)
```

Comment: Thanks! Works perfectly. I assume the * represents current directory. Not sure what you mean by use more () to execute more than one command. But not necessary for what I'm working on.

Comment: Yup `*` represents current (well it's a file-filter match), you could also pass in the directory as an arg (change `*` into `%1` and call as `<whatever> \windows\*` - Added a multi line and arg example.

Answer (score 0):

Building upon [Rudu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/75699/rudu)'s answer, and assuming `script.py` is located in the same directory (say `C:\Test`) as the following batch script, you could also run `script.py` recursively on all the directories present in `C:\Test`:

```
@echo off
for /d /r %%d in (*) do (
  echo Processing: %%d
  script.py "%%d"
)
```

The `FOR` help available from `cmd.exe` does not seem to mention it supports multiple modifiers, but it works on Windows 7.

Comment: Could you alter this script slightly to clean a directory (remove all files, but leave directory structure)

Comment: To delete all files recursively from a directory leaving the directory structure intact: `del /s /q /f "C:\Test Area\Target"` (`/s` walks the directory tree,`/q` won't prompt you for confirmation, `/f` will delete read-only files).

Comment: For some reason @BoReal answer is giving me some weird behaviour with TortoiseSVN the file that I ran the clean (outputfolder) says it is "obstructed" afterwards (the output folder and subdirectories are under source control). if i perform a tortoise clean directory, it says that the folder is not a working copy directory.

My guess: Deleting files inside the hidden .svn folder??? Sounds correct to me...